# Jenkins TFS Credential Binding

Tags: powershell, jenkins, tfs, jenkins-plugins, credentials

I have a large team of users using the same Active Directory credentials to log in to both TFS and Jenkins.

Example of AD accounts that can be used to access ***both TFS and Jenkins:***

- Company\JohnSmith
- Company\MaryJones
- Company\ServiceAccount

In Jenkins I've created a job that will merge code and check-in to TFS by executing a PowerShell script.

At the moment the PowerShell script uses **Company\ServiceAccount** to complete the merge and check-in in TFS. 
The problem with this is that even if **Company\JohnSmith** or **Company\MaryJones** kick off the Jenkins job, **Company\ServiceAccount** is recorded in TFS as having completed the check-in.

For better traceability I would like to be able to use the credentials of the user that is **currently logged into Jenkins** (be it JohnSmith or MaryJones or any of the other hundreds of users), 
and pass that username & password to the PowerShell script to connect to TFS. The outcome will be that in TFS it will show that **JohnSmith**/**MaryJones** did the check-in instead of **ServiceAccount**.

I have installed the following Jenkins plugins:

- Credentials Binding Plugin
- Credentials Plugin
- Plain Credentials
- Plugin Team Foundation Server Plug-in

I would like to be able to automatically pass the currently logged in user's credentials to the PowerShell script. Is this possible and how do I go about it?

I don't wan't to pass the same credentials each time, and I don't want to have the user re-enter their username/password as a parameter.

Comment: Don't think this is possible but a workaround could be in the Merge you can use the current user variable from Jenkins and put that in the merge note/comment field.

Comment: Thanks @RyanMcVicar. I'll use your suggestion if there's no other way

Answer (score 0):

The script is using the user/ TFS credentials  `Company\ServiceAccount`  which configured in Jenkins TFS plugin to do the TFS connection and check in operation.

There is no way to be able  to automatically pass the currently logged in Jenkins user's credentials to the PowerShell script.

As a workaround, you could do this through TFS build pipeline. Since your source control is managed in TFS and just use the Jenkins build.

You could simply add a [**Jenkins Queue Job**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/jenkins-queue-job) task which will queue a job on a Jenkins sever in TFS build definition.

Then add a powershell script task to do the merge and check in operation. About how to commit code to TFS with powerShell please refer this [blog](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/how-to-commit-code-tfs-powershell,2-990.html). Finally it will be the user who queued Jenkins Job, then checked in code in TFS.